# Structuring huge application assets

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic, architecture, request

We are about to completely rebuild a clients website, it currently has over 1000 pages.

There will be a cull, however my idea is to dynamically load assets based on what's on the page but I wanted to get feedback.

Let's say I have 100 global components (carousel,buttons,videos,Nah etc) currently over time we've just put all javascript for all components into a bundle.js file, same with css, however if a page only uses 3 of those 100 components it seems redundant to include everything.

So I guess my question is if it wrong to dynamically request only the components used, at runtime rather than loading all assets every time?

The big downside I can see is that almost every page will request new files, so caching will be harder, also more HTTP request would have to be made.

But if someone has a better idea please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest an evidence-based approach. Don't do anything without data to back up the decision.

My thoughts on an overall approach. I'm thinking about React as I write this, but nothing is React-specific.

- Server-render your content. It will then display to your users without needing your JavaScript bundle.
- Get a good CDN and/or something like varnish and cache each route/page response. You'll get fast response times no matter how big the site.
- Now, when the user visits a page they'll get it quickly and *then* you asynchronously download your JavaScript file that will breath life into the page.
- Because the user is already reading your page, you can take your time loading the JS - up to a second or two. If you think most of users will have decent internet (e.g. they're all in South Korea) then I'd go as big as a 2mb JS bundle before bothering to do chunking. Opinions will vary, it's up to you. If your users have bad internet (e.g. they're all in North Korea) then every kb counts and you should aim to be making the smallest chunks needed for each page. Both for speed and to respect the users' download quota.

Comment: Hey mate thanks for this, one curious thing though, when you say server render your content, you mean literally the templates correct?

Comment: Also, I like your point about chucking the javascript, however I'm just wondering if it's worth doing the same with css?

Comment: 1) If you use React and Node as the web server, then you can actually create your HTML on the server in the same way you'd create it in the browser. 2) For CSS, I inline it in HTML if the resulting HTML if small ([my site](http://www.dg707.com/)) but otherwise I'd apply the same rules as JS re size and chunking. [A good read](https://hpbn.co/).